# Sort NSMutableDictionary based on contents in NSMutable array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a array `NSMutableArray` with Values say 
10, 2, 13, 4.

Also there is `NSMutableDictionary` with values say 
(10, a), (20, b), (13, c), (2, d), (33, e)

I want to sort values in `NSMutableDictionary` in a way that result of dict should be (10, a), (2, d), (13, c)

Comment: Do you want to remove values that are not in array from dictionary?

Comment: View my answer, hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote for you function. Hope, it will help you:

```
- (void)removeUnnedful
{
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"a", [NSNumber numberWithInt:10],  
                          @"b", [NSNumber numberWithInt:20], 
                          @"c", [NSNumber numberWithInt:13], 
                          @"d", [NSNumber numberWithInt:2 ],
                          @"e", [NSNumber numberWithInt:33],  
                          nil];
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:2 ],
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:13],
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:14], nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *newDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    for (NSNumber *key in [dict allKeys])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", key);
        if ([array containsObject:key])
        {
            [newDict setObject:[dict objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
        }
    }

    for (NSNumber *key in [newDict allKeys])
        NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [newDict objectForKey:key]);

    [dict release];
    [array release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort order of keys and values in an instance of `NSDictionary` is not defined. (see [`[NSDictionary allKeys]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-CBHBEJJB))
As you already have an array of ordered keys, you can simply iterate over that and access the dictionary value for that key:

```
NSMutableArray* sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"10", @"2", @"13", @"4", nil];
NSDictionary* dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"a", @"10", @"b", @"20", @"c", @"13", @"d", @"2", @"e", @"33" , nil];
NSMutableDictionary* filteredDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for(id key in sortedArray)
{
    id value = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    if(value != nil)
    {
        [filteredDictionary setObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key] forKey:key];
    }
}
NSLog(@"%@", filteredDictionary);
```

Note that the default implementation of `[NSDictionary description]` sorts the output ascending per key (for keys of type `NSString`), but this is just a representation - `NSDictionaries` have no defined sort order so you shouldn't rely on the sorting of `allKeys` and `allValues`